# Should I use sxml or "simplexml" in the code?

Tags: php, simplexml, nsxmlparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you rename a tag in SimpleXML through a DOM object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694956/how-do-you-rename-a-tag-in-simplexml-through-a-dom-object)

[How do I create a duplicate of an XML element, but change the name of the element and delete the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921697/how-do-i-create-a-duplicate-of-an-xml-element-but-change-the-name-of-the-element)

```
$copy = $sxml->dogs;
unset($sxml->dogs);
$sxml->canine = $copy;
$sxml->canine->attributes()->type = "fiction";
```

I'm wondering if I should be actually using `$sxml`?

Comment: Can you expand on that please? I'm really not sure what you mean... You should be using `$sxml` is you instanciated a SimpleXMLElement object in there...

Comment: If you are trying to change the tag name, you'll have to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694956/how-do-you-rename-a-tag-in-simplexml-through-a-dom-object)

Comment: You just selected element, got copy of attributes and then change the value of type to 'fiction'. But that attribute is only a copy - if you change its value there's no impact to original xml document.

Comment: I think that this person answered the question wrong.  What the person did was 'unset' the name of the 'dogs' attribute, and then set it as copy.  The idea was to actually 'delete' it and then put it somewhere else.  What if they had changed the parent, you know?