# How can I change the name of an XML tag with PHP/SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

With SimpleXML, it is possible to add/change/delete attributes of a selected Node «on the fly» by typing e.g.

```
$child->addAttribute('n', $occ_order);
```

is there a way to alter the name of the $child element as well? I would expect something like

```
$child->setName('newTagName');
```

but I cannot find a corresponding function in the API.

Thanks in advance for your hints!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you rename a tag in SimpleXML through a DOM object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694956/how-do-you-rename-a-tag-in-simplexml-through-a-dom-object)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs[1] it looks like you can't. And it would be kind of weird if you could too - changing the name makes it a different/new element. What you want to do is delete that element and add a new one in the same place. However whilst there is a addChild method it doesn't look like there is a delete method. So maybe simpleXML is not the right tool here.

**Edit:** Indeed simpleXML does not provide a delete method. For info on how to do this, please see this answer[2].

1 http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

2 [Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php/262556#262556)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it with `unset()` if you know exactly where it is i.e. `$main->target` would be removed as `unset($main->target)` and add it again with `addchild()` i.e. `$main->addchild(name, value)`.

Comment: by the way, if you want it back as a variable i.e. $var you need to use $var = $main ->asXML();