# Parsing inline tags with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML & PHP to parse an XML element in the following form:

```
<element>
random text with <inlinetag src="http://url.com/">inline</inlinetag> XML to parse
</element>
```

I know I can reach *inlinetag* using *$element->inlinetag*, but I don't know how to reach it in such a way that I can basically replace the *inlinetag* with a link to the attribute *source* without using it's location in the text. The result would basically have to look like this:

```
here is a random text with <a href="http://url.com/">inline</a> XML
```

This may be a stupid questions, I hope someone here can help! :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you're trying to do. Could you please add an example what it should look like after your modification?

Comment: Are you trying to replace `<inlinetag>inline</inlinetag>` with `<a href="link">inline</a>` where `link` is equal to the source attribute ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, edited the post as well

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414814/how-can-i-change-the-name-of-an-xml-tag-with-php-simplexml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this using DOMElement.

One way to replace the element is by cloning it with a different name/attributes. Here is is a way to do this, using the accepted answer given on [How do you rename a tag in SimpleXML through a DOM object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694956/how-do-you-rename-a-tag-in-simplexml-through-a-dom-object)

```
function clonishNode(DOMNode $oldNode, $newName, $replaceAttrs = [])
{
    $newNode = $oldNode->ownerDocument->createElement($newName);
    foreach ($oldNode->attributes as $attr)
    {
        if (isset($replaceAttrs[$attr->name]))
            $newNode->setAttribute($replaceAttrs[$attr->name], $attr->value);
        else
            $newNode->appendChild($attr->cloneNode());
    }
    foreach ($oldNode->childNodes as $child)
        $newNode->appendChild($child->cloneNode(true));
    $oldNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $oldNode);
}
```

Now, we use this function to clone the inline element with a new element and attribute name. Here comes the tricky part: iterating over all the nodes will not work as expected. The length of the selected nodes will change as you clone them, as the original node is removed. Therefore, we only select the first element until there are no elements left to clone.

```
$xml = '<element>
        random text with <inlinetag src="http://url.com/">inline</inlinetag> XML to parse
    </element>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$nodes= $dom->getElementsByTagName('inlinetag');
echo $dom->saveXML(); //<element>random text with <inlinetag src="http://url.com/">inline</inlinetag> XML to parse</element>
while($nodes->length > 0) {
    clonishNode($nodes->item(0), 'a', ['src' => 'href']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML(); //<element>random text with <a href="http://url.com/">inline</a> XML to parse</element>
```

That's it! All that's left to do is getting the content of the element tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you want to achieve?

```
<?php
$data = '<element>
random text with 
<inlinetag src="http://url.com/">inline
</inlinetag> XML to parse
</element>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->inlinetag as $resource)
{
    echo 'Your SRC attribute = '. $resource->attributes()->src; // e.g. name, price, symbol
}
?>
```

Comment: No, I know how to reach inlinetag and it's attributes, but the problem I have is knowing where in the random text the inlinetag element is located. (So where to put <a href="http://url.com/">inline</a>)