# How to rename an Oracle XMLTYPE node

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, xmltype

I have an XMLType in PL/SQL and I need to rename some of the nodes and some of the values. For example:

```
<root>
   <fields>
        <a>foo</a>
        <b>bar</b>
   </fields>
</root>
```

I want to turn the above into this:

```
<root>
   <fields>
        <a>foo</a>
        <c>baz</c>
   </fields>
</root>
```

I know I can update the value like this:

```
SELECT UpdateXML(my_xml, '/root/fields/b/text()', 'baz')
  INTO my_xml_updated
  FROM DUAL;
```

The result is:

```
<root>
   <fields>
        <a>foo</a>
        <b>baz</b>
   </fields>
</root>
```

**But how can I update the node name from `<b>` to `<c>` (without affecting the contents of the node)?**

Comment: Your link points to a documentation of _Berkeley DB_, not to _Oracle DB_.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that aspect of the question since it was redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [XMLTRANSFORM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb08tra.htm) to rename a node. See also e.g. [Rename nodes with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271218).

```
with
xmldata as (select xmltype('<root>
  <fields>
    <a>foo</a>
    <b>bar</b>
  </fields>
</root>') val from dual),
stylesheet as (select '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Identity transformation -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Identity transformation overridden for element b -->
  <xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:element name="c">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>' val from dual)
select xmltransform(x.val, s.val) from xmldata x, stylesheet s;
```

Output:

```
XMLTRANSFORM(X.VAL,S.VAL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<root>
  <fields>
    <a>foo</a>
    <c>bar</c>
  </fields>
</root>
```

Comment: This discards the contents of `c` but can be modified like so:
    <xsl:template match="b">
      <xsl:element name="c">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: @wweicker: Yes it did, but now the answer is updated to meet the changed requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could define an xsl stylesheet that will make the change and use dbms_xslprocessor to do your modifications.